# WordPress update_post_meta updating with empty meta_value field

Tags: php, post-meta

I'm usuing custom fields pluging and my code has to fill them automitcally, everything works fine except 2 strings:

The way i'm getting the fields:

```
        foreach($postMeta as $key => $dataTmp) {
        if (strpos($key, 'field_') !== false) {
            $fieldData = unserialize($dataTmp[0]);

            $fields[] = array(
                'field' => $key,
                'name' => $fieldData['name']
            );
        }
    }
```

The way, i'm filling them:

```
    foreach($fields as $name => $field){
            if($field['name'] == 'local_players' && !empty($local_players)){
                update_post_meta($postID, '_' . $field['name'], $field['field']);
                update_post_meta($postID, $field['name'], $local_players);

            }elseif($field['name'] == 'away_players' && !empty($away_players)){
                update_post_meta($postID, '_' . $field['name'], $field['field']);
                update_post_meta($postID, $field['name'], $away_players);

            }else{
                update_post_meta($postID, '_' . $field['name'], $field['field']);
                update_post_meta($postID, $field['name'], $data['Match.'.$field['name']]);
            }

    }
```

Strings with the trouble are:

```
update_post_meta($postID, $field['name'], $local_players);
update_post_meta($postID, $field['name'], $away_players);
```

They fills the database with empty meta_value instead of values of $local_players and $away_players.  I've checked few times, that they are not empty.

For my example, their values are looks like this:

```
string(66) "84168|84171|11206|84174|102117|32083|84189|84186|84193|17787|84195"
```

What could be the reason of empty field?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've found the trouble. It was in logic.

Solution:

```
        foreach($fields as $name => $field){
            if($field['name'] == 'local_players'){
                if(!empty($local_players)){
                    update_post_meta($postID, '_' . $field['name'], $field['field']);
                    update_post_meta($postID, $field['name'], $local_players);
                }

            }elseif($field['name'] == 'away_players'){
                if(!empty($away_players)){
                    update_post_meta($postID, '_' . $field['name'], $field['field']);
                    update_post_meta($postID, $field['name'], $away_players);
                }

            }else{
                update_post_meta($postID, '_' . $field['name'], $field['field']);
                update_post_meta($postID, $field['name'], $data['Match.'.$field['name']]);
            }

    }
```